# Can any one explain me the below syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one expalin me the below syntax in java script as i am new to java script I am unable to understand the code below.

```
function validateAll(adMode, primaryAssetType, adCompanionAssetType) {
    var check = adStickervalidationcheck(adMode, 'new', primaryAssetType, adCompanionAssetType);

    if(check == true) {
        check=calculateTotalnoofImpression('${campaignid}');    
    }

    return check;   
}
```

Here in the above code why the keyword new is passed as parameter without using any object.

Here is the function definition code:

```
function adStickervalidationcheck(assetFormType,type,primaryAssetType,adCompanionAssetType)

{
    if((trim(document.assetform.priority.value))=="select")
    {
        alert("Please select the priority.");
        return false;
    }

    if((trim(document.assetform.impression.value).length)==0)
    {
        alert("Please enter Total Number of Impression.");
        return false;
    }
    if((trim(document.assetform.impression.value))=="0")
    {
        alert("Total No. Of Impression should not be Zero(0).");
        return false;
    }
    if(primaryAssetType=="Picture" || primaryAssetType=="Picture+Audio")
    {
        if((trim(document.assetform.picExt.value))=="select")
        {
            alert("Please select the extension of primary Image Asset File");
            return false;
        }
        if(type!="edit")
        {
            if((trim(document.assetform.asset_import.value))=="")
            {
                alert("Please import the primary Image Asset File");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if(primaryAssetType=="Audio" || primaryAssetType=="Picture+Audio")
    {
        if((trim(document.assetform.audExt.value))=="select")
        {
            alert("Please select the extension of primary Audio Asset File");
            return false;
        }
        if(type!="edit")
        {
            if((trim(document.assetform.asset_import_audio.value))=="")
            {
                alert("Please import the primary Audio Asset File");
                return false;
            }
        } 
    }


    if(adCompanionAssetType.contains("Picture") || adCompanionAssetType.contains("Video") || adCompanionAssetType.contains("Audio"))
    {
        if((trim(document.assetform.companion_assettype.value))=="select")
        {
            alert("Please select the extension of companion Asset File");
            return false;
        }
        if(type!="edit")
        {
            if((trim(document.assetform.asset_import2.value))=="")
            {
                alert("Please import the companion Asset File");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(adCompanionAssetType.contains("Audio") && adCompanionAssetType.contains("Picture"))
    {
        if((trim(document.assetform.companion_audio_Asset.value))=="select")
        {
            alert("Please select the extension of companion Audio Asset File");
            return false;
        }
        if(type!="edit")
        {
            if((trim(document.assetform.asset_import4.value))=="")
            {
                alert("Please import the companion Media Asset File");
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    if(adCompanionAssetType.contains("Video") && adCompanionAssetType.contains("Picture"))
    {
        if((trim(document.assetform.companion_video_Asset.value))=="select")
        {
            alert("Please select the extension of companion Video Asset File");
            return false;
        }
        if(type!="edit")
        {
            if((trim(document.assetform.asset_import4.value))=="")
            {
                alert("Please import the companion Media Asset File");
                return false;
            }

        }

    }

    if(adCompanionAssetType.contains("URL"))
    {
        if((trim(document.assetform.UrlAssetfile.value).length)==0)
        {
            alert("Please enter the companion URL Asset File");
            return false;
        }
    }


    if(assetFormType=="Subscriber" || assetFormType=="User")
    {


        if((document.assetform.male.checked==false) && (document.assetform.female.checked==false))
        {
            alert("Please Choose Gender. ");
            return false;
         }

        if((document.assetform.agegroup1.checked==false) &&
            (document.assetform.agegroup2.checked==false)&&
                (document.assetform.agegroup3.checked==false) &&
                    (document.assetform.agegroup4.checked==false))
                    {
                        alert("Please choose atleast one of the Age Group.");
                        return false;
                    }
         if((document.assetform.professiongroup1.checked==false) &&
            (document.assetform.professiongroup2.checked==false)&&
                (document.assetform.professiongroup3.checked==false) &&
                    (document.assetform.professiongroup4.checked==false) &&
                        (document.assetform.professiongroup5.checked==false)&&
                            (document.assetform.professiongroup6.checked==false))
                            {
                                alert("Please choose atleast one of the Profession.");
                                return false;
                            }

         if((trim(document.assetform.targetCity.value).length)==0)
            {
                alert("Please enter the targetCity");
                return false;
            }
         if((trim(document.assetform.targetArea.value).length)==0)
            {
                alert("Please enter the targetArea");
                return false;
            }
         if((trim(document.assetform.targetPincode.value).length)==0)
            {
                alert("Please enter the targetPinCode");
                return false;
            }


    }

     return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `new` is a keyword here since it is covered in **quotes**, its a string!!

Comment: without looking at `adStickervalidationcheck` function nobody can tell you. provide `adStickervalidationcheck` function code.

Comment: What in the code snippet do you find particularly unclear? What syntax do you not understand?

Comment: Now I have edited the code and posted the definition of the function also please can you answer me?

Comment: `adStickervalidationcheck()` does seem to check the `type` variable which is = to `'new'` from the other function call. Not sure it matters what you pass as long as it isn't the string `edit`. I can only see conditions in that function to check if `type` **does not** equal to `edit`. / `if(type!="edit")` The reason behind it? Only the person who created this very large an what appears to be unnecessary validations script will know "why". Validations script can be created many ways, this one seems like more work than needed.

Comment: Yeah this code is developed by previous developer and i am new to javascript @NewToJS

Comment: I think the reason for checking the `type` variable for `edit` is because that requires more fields/ validation. Seems like a messy way to function but as pointed out above. Only the coder will know the reason for use this method  / taking that path.

Comment: @CSiva If you want advice then mine would be: Find a better, cleaner way  to validate forms but before making any changes, ensure your new validation isn't going to mess anything else up.

Comment: can you post any link to validate forms in a nice way so that I can gothrough @NewToJS

Comment: @CSiva Sorry, I don't have any links for form validation. I write my own validation and some are different depending on the form inputs. I'm sure you can find some tutorials online to show how to validate different inputs, it's just down to you how you want to validate them and keep the function short and simple but just as effective.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help @NewToJS

Answer (score 0):

What your function does is validating if the form entry of all your "Assets" is valid.

The (kind of clumsy) validation is different if the type of your asset is "new" or "edit".

What you call a keyword "new" is just a string which distinguishes if we want to check the form for an addition or an edition because the rules of validation are different.